# Query polygons within a map-view boundary in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, google-maps, postgis

I am new to PostGIS.  I've got a table which contains boundaries of area in Polygon type.  I would like to display the polygon on Google map.  Each time, when google map view boundary is changed, the application should query PostGIS for any polygons in that map view.  Can someone guide me to start?

Comment: ST_Intersects(viewbbox, geom) where geom is the geometry column in your polygons table is the spatial function you are looking for. However, you will need to give more information about how you are displaying this, querying this, etc, from Google Maps.

Comment: Thanks!  When I display, I'll simply draw Polygons using the Lat/Lng pairs.  So, the input to my query is the lat/lng of NE and SE coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select * from Polygons where ST_Intersects(
    ST_MakeBox2D(ST_MakePoint(lon1, lat1), ST_MakePoint(lon2, lat2)),
    geom);
```

assuming that you have a table called Polygons and that your geometry field is called geom. You also need to make sure that you have a spatial index on the geometry field with:

```
Create index ix_spatial_geom on Polygons using gist (geom);
```

If you are planning on loading data from Postgis into google maps, have a look at the [AS_GeoJSON](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) function in Postgis, which allows you to create GeoJSON directly from Postgis, which you can then load into Google Maps directly, see this example: [load GeoJSON in Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson)

EDIT:

You can set the SRID when you import the data using the -s switch. It is highly advisable to explicitly set the SRID on a column either when you create the column or by running an update with [UpdateGeometrySRID](http://postgis.net/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html) afterwards, as this helps with both enforcing integrity, and enable conversion from one coordinate system to another.

Once you have you data in a specified coordinate system, you can also use [ST_Transfrom](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Transform.html) to convert from one coordinate system to another, on the fly, such as from 4326 to 3857 (the projected metres of Google Maps tiles).

Comment: Thank you!!!  However, your query does not return me any data although I know there must be polygons within the coordinates I passed in.  What's the best way to debug that?  By the way, my polygon type is geom geometry(Polygon,3347).

Comment: Here is my query. select * from test2 
where ST_Intersects(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_MakePoint(43.376395093503234, -80.09694519042966), ST_MakePoint(43.97234865260645, -78.72365417480466)),geom);    I've tried switching the lat/lng position.

Comment: I think I found why the query does not return me anything.  It looks like the coordinates saved in geometry data type are not matching the google map coordinates.

Comment: I think I figured out.  When I import my shp to postgis, I did not use the right coordinate system.  That's why the coordinates look so different from google map.  I used 4326 to import the data again and it works.  Here is my query:  `SELECT *
FROM test_2013_4326_f
WHERE geom && ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(-80.09694519042966, 43.376395093503234),
 ST_Point(-78.72365417480466, 43.97234865260645)),4326)`

Comment: You probably want to explicitly set the srid on your column on import, or run a bulk update to create the coorinates in the SRID you use, rather than using ST_SetSRID in your queries. I have updated my answer, based on your comments.

Answer (score 1):

ST_Intersects is probably the best solution for what you want.

If you are new to Postgis I recommend you to use their **[Postgis Cheat Sheet](http://www.postgis.us/downloads/postgis20_cheatsheet.pdf)**.  This document has all Postgis's basic and most used commands that you will probably use for now and it helps you to get it quickly without having to read the whole manual.

How to use ST_Intersect and all most used alternatives is there.